# Resizing Rectangular Boxes With Mouse

Tags: rectangles

I'm creating a system that allows users to create objects on the screen (as rectangles) and move them around and resize them using the corners and the mouse. My only problem is, when one of the objects is not a square and it is resized, the corner doesn't seem to match the mouse movement correctly.

For example, if I resize a box that is wider than it is tall, then the size of the box grows much more than the distance the mouse moved, but if the box is taller than it is wide, the box grows slower.

The algorithm that I'm currently using is as follows for resizing from the top-left of the box

```
((OldMouseX - NewMouseX) + (OldMouseY - NewMouseY)) / 2 * (1 / Screen.scale)
```

Where `Screen.scale` is the scale of the user window, which makes this work if the user is "zoomed" in or out.

I eventually came to this formula where I would try different numbers until the resized properly for `n`

```
((OldMouseX - NewMouseX) + (OldMouseY - NewMouseY)) / 2 * (1 / Screen.scale) * n
```

Where for `r` equals the ratio of `Width/Height` and `n` is about the number that is needed to make my boxes resize correctly.

> (r, n), (50, 0.04), (5, 0.34), (3, 0.51), (2, 0.67), (1, 1), (.5, 1.53), (1/3, 1.35),
>   (.2, 1.7), (.02, 1.96)

What algorithm do I need to find n with the given ratio?

Note: I'm usually a StackOverflow user so I know that a question like this doesn't belong there, but I was hoping that it would in this Stack Exchange branch. That being said, if this question doesn't follow the rules of Mathematics Stack Exchange, please let me know and I'll try my best to tailor the question for this website. Thanks!

Comment: when resizing do you want to keep the aspect ratio of the objects?

Comment: Yes, that was my intent

Answer (score 0):

Think of the mouse coordinate as one corner of the new bounding rectange that is to be filled with the object without affecting the aspect ratio.
So if the object is $a\times b$ and the mouse was mooved x,y , the scaled a is $a+\mathrm{min}(\frac{y\,a}{b},x)$ and the scaled b is $b+\mathrm{min}(\frac{x\,b}{a},y)$

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get this to function correctly... My implementation is as follows:
a = Object.width, b = Object.height, x = OldMouseX - NewMouseX, y = OldMouseY - NewMouseY;
Object.width += min((y * a) / b, x);
Object.height += min((x * b) / a, y);

Comment: It looks right, are you maybe falling into the pitfall of integer division?
Try min((y * 1.0 * a) / b,x) . And another thing. This method is numerically instable and will with many resizing maybe distort the aspect ratio. To circumvent you could save the aspect ratio of each object.
double r=a*1.0/b;
...
width+=min(y*r,x);
height+=min(x/r,y);

Comment: I actually have done that, my real implementation stores the aspect ratio on mouse down and then only resizes for real the height of the object, and then the width is resized purely based off of the height and the ratio. I'll try some things when I get back to work today and let you know how they turn out